# concatenating using C function to large char*

Tags: c, string, memory, char

I am trying to concatenate char* and const string but the system hangs. following is the code

```
unsigned long long size = 2*pow(10,18);
char* string = malloc(size);    
strcat(string," ");
```

I am not sure how to resolve the error. Using Dev c/c++ in windows 10.

Edit: Thank you for all your comments and answer. I have made the change in my code. But it still gives the same problem.
It does not print the statement and still hangs.

```
char* string = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
if(string=NULL){
    printf("unsuccessful memory allocation");
}

strcat(string," ");
```

Comment: check for return value of `malloc()` ... `if(string==NULL)printf("unsuccessful memory allocation");`

Comment: then `*string = 0;` or copy string before `strcat`.

Comment: The most likely reason is that you don't have that much memory and `malloc` returns `NULL`.

Comment: That is a stupendously large amount of memory to request. I don't even have a disk drive of that capacity.

Comment: maybe are you trying to convert double number 2*pow(10,18) to string?

Comment: It is possible that I may have made a wrong prediction regarding memory. I am rethinking that.

Comment: @GerardoSánchez No , OP is not trying to convert `double` to `char *` .  He is trying to allocate that much memory to `char *`.

Comment: As others have mentioned, the `malloc` is probably returning `NULL`. But, after you fix that (with a check and cut down of size), you should insert `string[0] = 0;` before you do the `strcat`

Comment: I made an edit in the question. I am still having the same issue. I will need more memory than this for sure.

Comment: @CraigEstey: string[0]=0; did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @denis Please remember not to edit original code in question . This renders answers and comments posted before obsolete.

Comment: It may not be the solution, but the `string[0] = 0;` ensures that the `strcat` will append starting at the _first_ char of the string [which is what you want]. Otherwise, `malloc` might return an area where the first 50 bytes are non-zero and `strcat` will skip past them and append at `&string[50]` [which is _not_ what you want]. If you've cut back your malloc size to something sane [and it returns non-null], this gets rid of segfault, but the code shown could not "hang", just by itself

Comment: Rolled back to show the later error that was commented on.

Comment: Sorry missed out to follow the convention. Edited the question to follow the order in which I asked and made the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most probable reason might be that `malloc()` **might fail to allocate the amount of memory you request for**. Always check if the memory is successfully allocated or not this way :

```
char *p; //some pointer
p=malloc(size*sizeof(char));

if(p==NULL)
{
    printf("unsuccessfull memory allocation");
    exit(1);
}
```

> **Note :**
>
> - `malloc()` returns the address of newly allocated memory on **successful allocation**.
> - if memory **allocation is not successful** then, it returns `NULL`

---

And as [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) has mentioned in the comments, your `strcat()` will fail even if allocation is successful,

try initialize the `string` before using :

```
*string = 0;
```

or copy `string` before `strcat()` function.

Comment: I tested this. It does not go to if condition. Means it allocating the memory.

Comment: As @BLUEPIXY wrote, `strcat` will fail even if there is enough memory.

Comment: If he actually has 1e18 bytes (~1e9TB), there is probably a NULL in there somewhere. The `strcat` is broken, but probably won't fail.  I sure would like 1e9TB of RAM myself. @denis, you should recheck your test.

Comment: @denis  it must be `if(string == NULL)`, not `if(string=NULL)`

Comment: @CherubimAnand: Thank you that was breaking the code.

Comment: no problem, pleasure helping you :) but as @ameyCU has mentioned, don't change the question as it makes the answers irrelevant for future viewers to understabd

Comment: @ameyaCU and CherubimAnand: sorry missed out on that. I should have extended my question rather than modifying the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to allocate 20000000TB. You certainly don't have that much memory. malloc will be failing and returning a NULL pointer which you are then trying to write to!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the cause of the fail is the size of memory you are trying to malloc.

> unsigned long long size = 2*pow(10,18);
>
> char* string = malloc(size);

you are trying to malloc: 2000000000000000000 bytes

Thats 2 EB (EB: exabyte) 1 EB = 1000000 GB